# Which IDE's run on Ubuntu 14.04 and work for Brightscript Development?

Tags: application-development, eclipse, ide

> **Roku BrightScript** is a powerful scripting language that makes it easy
>   and quick to build media and networked applications for embedded
>   devices. The language has integrated support for BrightScript
>   Components, a library of lightweight components. The APIs of the
>   platform (device) BrightScript is running on are all exposed to
>   BrightScript as BrightScript Components.

I found eclipse is an IDE for the brightscript development. But I want to know, is there any other IDE ? Please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a correct answer for this, however, I will throw a non IDE option out there.

There is a definition bundle for Sublime Text.  This isn't an IDE, but still an option depending on what you prefer.

To install Sublime Text 2 in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Once Sublime is installed, you can install the bundle with the following.

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/
git clone git://github.com/cmink/BrightScript.tmbundle.git
```

Information on Brightside Definition Bundle

https://github.com/cmink/BrightScript.tmbundle